# How to solve abstract functional equations?

Tags: equation-solving

**Question:**

If the function f[x] defined on x > 0 is a monotone function, and f[f[x] + Log[1/2, x]] == 3 for any x of x > 0, what is the value of x when f[x] == 0?

Cannot be resolved using the following method:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ForAll[x, x > 0, f[f[x] + Log[1/2, x]] == 3]
Reduce[f[x] == 0 && x > 0, x]
```

Comment: 1. The line `ForAll[x, x > 0, f[f[x] + Log[1/2, x]] == 3]` doesn't make sense at all, once again, please read the document carefully, don't learn by guessing. 2. How do you get the result `x==1/E`?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9ohN.png

Comment: Your symbols are obviously polluted. I bet you've modified the context of the notebook. Try executing `Context[]`, probably the output isn't `Global\``. Modifying `Clear["Global\`*"]` to `Clear["\`*"]` will probably fix the problem.

Comment: Without manually modifying the code, the result after adding Clear["Global '*"] is x==1/E

Comment: ……行，没看懂我的话我就用中文再说一遍。你这笔记本的上下文改过，先执行下`Context[]`看看输出是啥。

Comment: The problem has been solved

Comment: 那就把你问题里错误的陈述改过来。

Comment: Äigentlech isch di offizielli Sprooch do Änglisch, wil wemmer alli schrybe wie mer wei, denn git's bald es Gnuusch.

Comment: @Roman I know, of course. But OP is clearly having difficulty in understanding my comment(s) in English, so I think this is better than nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
f\left(f(x)-\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}\right)=3
$$
Assuming that $f$ is invertible, apply $f^{-1}$ on both sides:
$$
f(x)-\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}=f^{-1}(3)
$$
and therefore
$$
f(x)=f^{-1}(3)+\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}
$$
Now we still need the value of $a=f^{-1}(3)$ and for that we can use Mathematica: it's a tricky equation involving lots of branch cuts,

```
f[x_] = a - Log[1/2, x];
Reduce[f[f[x] + Log[1/2, x]] == 3] // FullSimplify

(*    C[1] == 0 && a Log[2] == Log[4]    *)
```

which means that $a=f^{-1}(3)=\frac{\ln 4}{\ln 2}=2$, and therefore
$$
f(x)=2+\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}
$$

```
f[x_] = 2 - Log[1/2, x];
f[f[x] + Log[1/2, x]]

(*    3    *)
```

Comment: A much simpler way with Mathematica is `Solve[f[f[x] + Log[1/2, x]] == 3, f[x]]` which results in `{{f[x]->(Log[x]+Log[2] (f^(-1))[3])/Log[2]}}` and a warning.

Comment: I disagree, @user64494. You got lucky here, but remember that Mathematica treats `f[x]` as a *symbol*, not as a *function*, and will happily treat `f[2x]` as a completely different/unrelated symbol. Slightly more complex functional equations will therefore fail miserably with your suggestion.